# Could not connect to localhost:port during start pseudo_hdfs4

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I am trying to run unittest for beeswax app.

In my machine hdfs and hive work correctly, but when I am running unittest, which creates  pseudo_hdfs4, i am getting error:

```
StructuredThriftTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:port (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to localhost:port',)
```

**Test name:** *beeswax.tests.TestBeeswaxWithHadoop*

**Logs:**

```
beeswax.server.hive_server2_lib: INFO: Opening beeswax thrift session for user test
root: INFO: Thrift exception; retrying: Could not connect to lwo1-lhp-f70489:44981
root: INFO: Thrift exception; retrying: Could not connect to lwo1-lhp-f70489:44981
root: WARNING: Out of retries for thrift call: OpenSession
root: INFO: Thrift saw a transport exception: Could not connect to lwo1-lhp-f70489:44981
beeswax.test_base: ERROR: Failed to open Hive Server session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bdemydov/Projects/roku/roku-hue-3-12/hue-3.12.0/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/test_base.py", line 131, in get_shared_beeswax_server
    db.open_session(user)
  File "/home/bdemydov/Projects/roku/roku-hue-3-12/hue-3.12.0/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/dbms.py", line 320, in open_session
    return self.client.open_session(user)
  File "/home/bdemydov/Projects/roku/roku-hue-3-12/hue-3.12.0/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 1263, in open_session
    return self._client.open_session(user)
  File "/home/bdemydov/Projects/roku/roku-hue-3-12/hue-3.12.0/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 604, in open_session
    res = self._client.OpenSession(req)
  File "/home/bdemydov/Projects/roku/roku-hue-3-12/hue-3.12.0/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/thrift_util.py", line 389, in wrapper
    raise StructuredThriftTransportException(e, error_code=502)
StructuredThriftTransportException: Could not connect to lwo1-lhp-f70489:44981 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to lwo1-lhp-f70489:44981',)
```

Comment: Well, is there a thriftserver running at 44981 port? Those logs don't say localhost

Comment: Is your desktop/conf/pseudo-distributed.ini valid and did you run http://gethue.com/tutorial-how-to-run-the-hue-integration-tests/?